# syntax error operand expected (error token is "-") in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

Inside the script there is one error i am getting as `syntax error operand expected (error token is "-")` at line 109

```
#!/bin/ksh
..............
while read file
do 
    upd_time=$((`date +%s`-`stat -c %Y ${file}`))     #At this line getting error
    file_nm=`basename "${file}"`
..................
```

In the above live getting error as `syntax error operand expected (error token is "-")`.

Comment: You'll get a possibly clearer error message if you correctly quote the expansion of `$file`. Also, you should use `$(...)`, not backticks, for command substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `stat` when `file` doesn't have a value:

```
$ unset file
$ stat -c %Y $file
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
```

If you correctly quote `$file`, you'll get a slightly better error message:

```
$ stat -c %Y "$file"
stat: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
```

If you aren't positive about the contents of your input file, try verifying that `$file` actually contains an existing file before calling `stat`:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do 
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue

    upd_time=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y "$file") ))
    file_nm=$(basename "$file")
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner one of the file was missing

Comment: but @chepner in script `echo $file` & file both were missing so root cause would be both or just only file missing. I just want to confirm

Comment: Both would be separate errors resulting from attempting to use an empty string where a non-empty string was expected. That's why I check once, not just to see if `file` is non-empty, but to see if it actually refers to a file that you can stat. (`basename` will work on a path whether the name exists or not, but supposedly future uses of `file_nm` would require the file to exist.)

Comment: any idea on below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75007309/add-exception-handling-when-file-missing-in-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your error:

tmp.txt:

```
/bin/sh

/bin/bash
```

test.sh:

```
while read file; do
  upd_time=$((`date +%s`-`stat -c %Y ${file}`))
  echo $upd_time
done < tmp.txt
```

output:

```
44421445
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
-bash: 1671714632-: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "-")
```

**You have a blank line in your input file.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, means if i remove extra blank line then my issue get resolved ?? Actually in main script file there is no any extra blank line but i haven't use `echo $upd_time` in shell script.

Comment: Not your script file, but the input file to the loop.

Comment: I.e., `$file` is expanding to an empty string.

Comment: @chepner `$file` is a csv file which is in another file directory.

Comment: You may be *expecting* it to be the name of a CSV file, but it's not.