# Add exception handling when file missing in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Inside shell script it is picking some files from UNIX directory. Sometimes when any of these file missed then throw error & shell script got failed. I need to add `Exceptional Handling` in shell script. Here is the below shell script where it is picking files from directory.

```
#!/bin/ksh
..........
while read file
do
    upd_date=$((`date +%s`-`stat -c %Y ${file}`))
    file_nm=`basename "${file}"`
    if [[ `lsof | grep "${file_nm}"` != '' || $upd_date -lt 60 ]];
    then
        log_info "Waiting for the file ${file} to complete transfer/skip"
    else
        log_info "Data file found ${file}"
    fi
done<${TEMP}/filepath
...............

exit 0
```

In the line `upd_date=..` throwing error whenever file missed & shell script got failed. So I need to add exception handling if file missed then it will show in log & script will execute successfully.

Comment: `ksh` is not `bash` though.  Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: @Jetchisel I changed tag to ksh only. Could you please suggest me here only.

Comment: `ksh` doesn't really have exception handling. Verify that `$file` actually expands to a valid file name *before* trying to use it.

Comment: @chepner I've updated question having file name.

Comment: `while ...; do [ -f "$file" ] || continue; ...; done` ?

Comment: Or just `while ...; do upd_date=$( ... ) || continue` (note `$()` vice `$(())`)

Comment: Polling a file with `lsof` is a terrible way to determine when a file is complete.  Have the writer write to a tmp file and then (atomically) rename it.   The renamed file should be treated as immutable; as soon as it exists, it is complete.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks a lot William to comment on it. I tried this one also `while ...; do upd_date=$( ... ) || continue` but again getting same error.

Comment: or can we use `file_missing` function and use as `Exceptional handling` if file got miss then it will throw an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "throw an error"?  The shell does not have any type of "throw" mechanism (other than sending a signal to itself), and generally "throw an error" in this context just means "emit an error message".  With the code you've shown, if the file is missing I would expect a bunch of error messages, but the script itself won't terminate.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I mean when shell execute then in terminal getting error.

Comment: But it does not appear that your script is actually failing.  I would expect to see a lot of error messages, but the script will still get to `exit 0`.  There does not appear to be anything that would cause your script to fail.  Are you asking "how can I make the script abort when it sees that a file does not exist?", or are you saying "my script is failing when a file does not exist, and I want it not to do that"  Saying you want to "Add exception handing"  suggests that you want the behavior to be what it already is, so it's not really clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Earlier when any file got missed then script failed &  stopped work.  I just want that if any file got missed then script will run continue to next iteration or next statement without any fail.

Comment: The issue is that when the file does not exist, the content of the string you are sending to `$(())` is not a valid expression, so `ksh` is aborting.  Rather than trying to cram everything in one line, you could be more explicit and do something like `age=$(stat -c %Y "$file); if test -n "$age"; then ...`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell If i use `while ...; do [ -f "$file" ] || continue; upd_date=$( ... ) || continue;` then is it a good practice?

Comment: checking for the existence of the file and `continue`ing seems reasonable, but I think the whole approach should be changed.  Ideally, the producer (the process writing the file) would not allow any ambiguity.  Write the file somewhere else and then create the final final by creating the link (hard link) only after the file is complete and will not be modified.  This allows you to avoid the whole problem of checking update time.

Comment: @Fravadona when i use above your code `while ...; do [ -f "$file" ] || continue; ...; done` then script is not running continuously. Earlier it was running continuously, so i stopped and then rerun which should not be like this. The script should run without stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` in between `while` loop. `continue` will skip the current iteration in for, while and until loop.

```
#!/bin/ksh
..........
while read file
do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue;
  upd_date=$((`date +%s`-`stat -c %Y ${file}`))
  file_nm=`basename "${file}"`
  if [[ `lsof | grep "${file_nm}"` != '' || $upd_date -lt 60 ]];
  then
    log_info "Waiting for the file ${file} to complete transfer/skip"
  else
    log_info "Data file found ${file}"
  fi
done<${TEMP}/filepath
...............

exit 0
```